# Sorting Array not working correctly

Tags: php

The sorting of array in alphabetical order is not outputting correctly.

It outputted as:

Demo
qwerty
Demo3
Test1
Test2
New1

Instead of:

Demo
Demo3
New1
qwerty
Test1
Test2

Code:

```
<?php

$dbresults= array ( "0"  => array ( "id" => "1",
                              "cb_boutiquename1" => "Test1",
                              "cb_boutiquename2" => "Test2",
                              "cb_boutiquename3" => "New1"
                                 ),
              "1" => array ( "id" => "2",
                              "cb_boutiquename1" => "Demo",
                              "cb_boutiquename2" => "qwerty",
                              "cb_boutiquename3" => "Demo3"
                                 )
            );

    function sortarray($a, $b) {
        return strcmp($a["cb_boutiquename$i"], $b["cb_boutiquename$i"]);
    }

    usort($dbresults, "sortarray");

    while (list($key, $value) = each($dbresults)) {
        $results[] = $value ;
    }

    foreach($results as $result) {
        $i = 1;
        while (array_key_exists("cb_boutiquename$i", $result)) {
        if ($result["cb_boutiquename$i"] !='') {
            echo '<a href=' . cbSef( 'index.php?option=com_comprofiler&task=page&user=' . (int) $result['id'] . '&b=' . $i . getCBprofileItemid( false )) . '>' . $result["cb_boutiquename$i"] . '</a><br />';
        }
        ++$i;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Comment: also http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php

Comment: $I is out of scope in the sortarray() function

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php sould do it. sort() doesn't preserve array indices. and there is no need to bother with usort()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that in here:

```
function sortarray($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a["cb_boutiquename$i"], $b["cb_boutiquename$i"]);
}
```

$i is undefined so you are basically comparing one undefined array offset with another.

If you want to specify which of the cb_boutiquename fields to specify at runtime then what you probably want to do is include the $i in the function, on php this can be done with a function that returns a closure (PHP 5.3+).

```
function getSorter($idx){
       return function($a, $b) use ($idx) {
           return strcmp($a["cb_boutiquename$idx"], $b["cb_boutiquename$idx"]);
       };
}
```

This returns a function that closes over the supplied argument and is appropriate for use as a comparison function for usort. So for your sort call you would use:

```
usort($dbresults, getSorter(1));
```

Or for a more general solution that does not assume the cb_boutiquename prefix on the properties  you can change this to

```
function getSorter($idx){
       return function($a, $b) use ($idx) {
           return strcmp($a[$idx], $b[$idx]);
       };
}
usort($dbresults, getSorter("cb_boutiquename1"));
```

This will allow you to sort any array of arrays by an one of the indexes.

**UPDATE** 
I completely misunderstood the goal of this exercise. What you want to do is to flatten your array prior to doing any sorting.

```
    $dbresults= array ( "0"  => array ( "id" => "1",
                          "cb_boutiquename1" => "Test1",
                          "cb_boutiquename2" => "Test2",
                          "cb_boutiquename3" => "New1"
                             ),
          "1" => array ( "id" => "2",
                          "cb_boutiquename1" => "Demo",
                          "cb_boutiquename2" => "qwerty",
                          "cb_boutiquename3" => "Demo3"
                             )
        );

// flatten out the array
$results = array();
foreach($dbresults as $k=>$v){
    foreach ($v as $key=>$value) {
          if (substr($key, 0,15) == "cb_boutiquename"){
              $results[] = array("id"=>$v["id"], "cb_boutiquename"=>$value, "i"=>substr($key, 15));
          }
    }

}

usort($results, function($a, $b){ return strcasecmp($a["cb_boutiquename"], $b["cb_boutiquename"]); });
foreach($results as $result){
    echo '<a href=' . cbSef( 'index.php?option=com_comprofiler&task=page&user=' . (int) $result['id'] . '&b=' . $result["i"] . getCBprofileItemid( false )). '>' . $result["cb_boutiquename"] . '</a><br />'."\n";
}
```

Comment: @Greystoke are you using php 5.3 or greater?

Comment: @Graystoke sorry... I realized I forgot the semicolon after the return statement, updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: It is now outputting: Demo qwerty Demo3 Test1 Test2 New1

Comment: I misunderstood your question entirely...you need to flatten the array prior to doing any sorting. I will post a solution.

Comment: Thank you. cb_boutiquename goes up to cb_boutiquename30 in the array. Do I need to add a line for each of the cb_boutiquename. Like: $results[] = array("id"=>$v["id"], "cb_boutiquename"=>$v["cb_boutiquename30"], "i"=>3);

Comment: @Graystoke updated code to allow an arbitrary number of elements starting with cb_boutiquename

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your `sortarray` function, use simply this:

`asort($dbresults);`

No need to reinvent the wheel. Read about it [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php)

Comment: I replaced usort($dbresults, "sortarray");  with asort($dbresults); but it didn't sort them correctly. It gave: Test1 Test2 New1 Demo qwerty Demo3

Comment: Yeah, but the idea was to change your _whole_ `sortarray` function with `asort($dbresults);`... there is no need to build a new function to do something that PHP already does for itself... In the documentation link I placed on the answer you have a few examples explaining how to use it.